# PyDev OS independent project file

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

Is there any way I could use the same PyDev configuration file across two different operating systems? that is I want to replace all the os specific paths with environmental variables to make this configuration file os independent but cannot really see how could I achieve this goal without resorting to manual editing of the this file.
It's not obvious for me how to do it from the eclipse/pydev level.

Can anybody help?

Below is an example of an os tied configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?><pydev_project>
<pydev_variables_property name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_VARIABLE_SUBSTITUTION">
<key>GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE</key>
<value>C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine</value>
</pydev_variables_property>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>/Cozeebaby</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/PyAMF</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/antlr3</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/django_1_3</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/enum</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/fancy_urllib</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/google-api-python-client</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER">Default</pydev_property>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION">python 2.6</pydev_property>
</pydev_project>
```